# Perl or Awk RegEx to add % at the end of line, current Awk RegEx is failing

Tags: regex

I have a line that reads as phu-ser4505 at the moment i have managed to use filters to remove so it looks like %ser4505 but I want to add another % at the end of the line so it looks like %ser4505% how ca n i do this using a relgular expression.

I got help with the regEX but it still failing for me: this is the regex

awk -F'-' '{printF "%"$2"% } '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
sed 's/[^-]*\-\(.*\)/%\1%/' <<< "phu-ser4505"
```

... or `awk`:

```
awk -F'-' '{printf "%"$2"%"}' <<< "phu-ser4505"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am limited to using this within perl,java, awk or glob style how can i adapt this for either the options i mentioned?

Comment: It doesn't like that it gives me a filtering process error for input string :(

Comment: I don't get you. Can you explain your current problem?

Comment: when i try and use the awk expression you have just provided it doesnt work all it says is filter error! filter processing error;input string phu-ser4505. The way i am using the regex is as a filter in HP operations orchestrations. I dont know if this makes it more complicated or confuses you

Comment: Its still failing but i will mark your answer as useful because it looks right but its just not working in my case for some reason :(

Comment: You should edit your question and add as much information as possible to *reproduce* your problem. Then me or somebody other might solve it. (I'll go sleeping for today)